# python Using Regular Expression to find letters in a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the first vowel in a word, and remove all the letters before the first occurrence of vowel, finally return the left of the word. i thought i can use a list to do that, first find 'a' in the word, and get the first part separated by 'a', and then find 'e'.....but i want to simplify it with regular expression, i am thinking if theres a way that i can find all the five vowels at the same time and get a index of the first one, then it will be easy to do next step. so i might need some help. i am a newer in regular expression, does anyone have an idea about this?

i have problems again. this is the code i write according to the suggestion made by @Martijin.

```
import re
def pigify():
    user_input=raw_input()
    sentence=re.sub(r'\b([aeiou])([a-z]*)\b',r'\1\2'+'hay',user_input,re.I)
    sentence1=re.sub(r'\b(qu)([a-z]*)\b',r'\2\1'+'ay',sentence,re.I)
    sentence2=re.sub(r'\b([^aeiou]*)(\w*)\b',r'\2\1'+'ay',sentence1,re.I)
    print sentence2
    return
pigify()
```

if i input:

```
quiet askhj a dhjsadf skdhyksj qdksdj y
```

i would like to get:

```
ietquay askhjhay ahay adfdhjsay yksjskdhay qdksdjay yay
```

but now i've only complished the first two steps:1. find the vowel-started word and add 'hay' at the end of it, 2.find the 'qu'-started word and move 'qu' to the end then add 'ay'.the 3rd step is to find the left words in the sentence and for every word, find the first vowel or 'y'(when 'y' is not the first letter) in it, move all the letters before the vowel to the end and add 'ay'. the code run as result like this:

```
ietquayayaskhjhay ay ahay dhjsadf skdhyksj qdksdj y
```

i guess i didn't use \b in a right way, because re.sub use replacement to replace the blocks. how to get it right? by the way, i've accomplished another version with 'for' loop and 'if|else',this is the code, i think there must be a way to simplify it.

```
def SieveWord(user_input):
    return user_input.split(' ')
def UpperToLower(user_input):
    return user_input.lower()

vowel=['a','e','i','o','u']                               
transform_input=UpperToLower(raw_input())            
input_list=SieveWord(transform_input)                
u=[]                                                 

for word in input_list:                              
    if len(word)!=1:                                 
        if word[0] in vowel:                         
            word+='h'                                
        else:
            if word[0]+word[1]=='qu':
                word=word[2:]+'qu'                   
            else:
                for letter in word:                 
                    if letter in vowel or (letter=='y' and word[0]!='y'):
                        position=word.index(letter)         
                        removepart=word[0:position]         
                        word=word[position:]+removepart     
                        break                                                    
    elif word in vowel:                              
        word+='h'                                    
    u.append(word+'ay')                              
for d in u:
    print d,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us some code, we will help you with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: sorry for not giving the code, i'll make the question better  understood next time.

Comment: By now you have altered the question quite considerably, making my answer invalid. Try not to do that too often.

Comment: sorry, i can make another question if you require. new comer, not so familiar with the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove all non-vowels at the start of a word:

```
re.sub(r'\b[^aeoui]*', '', inputstring, flags=re.I)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = 'School'
>>> re.sub(r'\b[^aeoui]*', '', inputstring, flags=re.I)
'ool'
```

The `[^...]` negative class matches anything that is *not* a vowel (with the `re.I` flag making sure it'll ignore case). The `\b` anchor matches the position in a string just before or after a word. The `re.I` makes the  In the example above, `\b` matches the start, and the negative class matches the `Sch` characters, as they are not in the class.

Comment: thank you every much. now i have a better understanding of re.sub,what if i want to move 'Sch' to the end of the word, i mean get word like 'oolSch', can i still use re.sub(...,repl,...) to make that?

Comment: and more particular way to describe it: could repl include variables or the items need replacing itself?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `re.sub()` pattern to capture groups and refer to those in the replacement pattern: `re.sub(r'\b([^aeoui]*)(\w*)\b', r'\2\1', inputstring, flags=re.I)` would swap the first and second part of a word.

Comment: got it. thank you. i was using this kind of regular expression to make the Pig Latin Translator. it's the major problem i guess.

Comment: sorry to bother again. is there any way that i can use more than one pattern in one re.sub?

Comment: Yes you can, but it'll be easier to make separate replacements.